Django template compare templatetag result with variable?
I've got template tag, that returns selected (earlier) location name of the store:

@register.simple_tag( takes_context=True)
def getSelectedLocation(context):
    request = context['request']
    locationId = request.session.get('locationId') 
    if (locationId):
        location = Location.objects.get(id = locationId)
    else:
        location = Location.objects.first()
    return location.locationName

and in my template I'd like to compare it with actual variables:
 {%for eq in obj.equipment.all %} 
                
 {%if getSelectedLocation != 'eq.storageLocation.locationName' %}
 something 
 {%endif%}
 {%endfor%}
 

(in general, template tag works ok, ie/ if called like {% getSelectedLocation %} returns correct name). But comparison won't work.
Is it possible to do it that way? I think I can't move that logic to a view, as it enumerates over obj object foreign key values...
Any suggestions?

I'd suggest figuring out a way to do this in the templatetag as logic in templates starts to get messy. But you could always use something like {% with getSelectedLocation as location %} ... {% if location == "blah" %}... {% endwith %}

That makes sense, since here it will not evaluate the template tag, it will just look for a variable named getSelectedLocation, and there is no such thing, hence the problem.
You can store the result in a variable, like:
{% getSelectedLocation as selectedLocation %}
{%for eq in obj.equipment.all %} 
    {%if selectedLocation != 'eq.storageLocation.locationName' %}
        something 
    {%endif%}
{%endfor%}

Yes! Thanks man. That was something I was looking for (and actualy, forget , because knew it in the past...)
